# Errata in Exploring JS on Object.assign text?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, prototype

[*Exploring JS*](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html#Object_assign) by Axel Rauschmayer Emanauten, a very popular book on ES6, says,

> If you want the clone to have the same prototype as the original, you can use Object.getPrototypeOf() and Object.create():
>
> ```
> function clone(orig) {
>    const origProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(orig);
>    return Object.assign(Object.create(origProto), orig);
> }
> ```

That seems not to be true though,

```
var a = {a:1};
var o1 = Object.create(a);
Object.getPrototypeOf(o1); //shows {a:1} of course
var o2 = Object.assign(o1);
Object.getPrototypeOf(o2); // also shows {a:1}
```

So why do they say "same prototype as the original" in clone? It seems `Object.assign` already gives it the same prototype as the original, and it seems the `clone()` they're creating copies all of the enumerable methods from the prototype, losing the link to the prototype entirely.

Comment: From the beginning of the section you linked to *"This method merges the sources into the target: It modifies target, first copies all enumerable own (non-inherited) properties of source_1 into it, then all own properties of source_2, etc. At the end, it returns the target."* This paragraph says that `Object.assign` returns the first argument passed to it, i.e. your application doesn't actually clone the object.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what `clone` does at all. You're not using `Object.create` with the prototype, and you're not using `Object.getPrototypeOf` on the object you want to clone, and you don't use `Object.assign` with two parameters. All those are important parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var o2 = Object.assign(o1);
```

is equal to:

```
var o2 = o1;
```

as Object.assign returns the first argument. The following arguments are copied into the first one, so you may do:

```
var o2=Object.assign({},o1);
```

And you see that they are equal except the prototype...

Comment: Yea, so the key is that it's not returning a new object. It's mutating the argument. That's cool. I got confused what in JS mutates and what returns anew.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Right. Hence why he is using `function clone(orig) { return Object.assign({}, orig); }` as clone implementation, not `function clone(orig) { return Object.assign(orig); }`.